# How to query for documents with field 'name' not equal to both 'RELAY' and 'INFRARED', Firestore Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection `devices` of documents having a field `name` with 5 possible string values `'LIGHT', 'TEMP', 'SOUND', 'INFRARED', 'RELAY'`. How do I query for only documents with field `name` not equal both `'INFRARED'` and `'RELAY'`?

The solution I thought of was to use compound query

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('devices')
      .where(
        'name',
        isNotEqualTo: 'RELAY',
      )
      .where(
        'name',
        isNotEqualTo: 'INFRARED',
      );
```

But this didn't work at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is now `not-in` - similar to `in` which matches a single field to any entry in an array, but in this case NOT in the array.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_not-in_and_array-contains-any

Limited to an array of 10 entries or less, which fits your use-case of two values.

Also Note: any field used in a query will automatically `reject` all documents that do not have that field.